# No Enlightened badge to go with Nice Answer on first-posted accepted answer?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, badges

I got Nice Answer for [How to deal with combat immediately after entering room through narrow passage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/66983/how-to-deal-with-combat-immediately-after-entering-room-through-narrow-passage/66984#66984) more than two hours ago, but no sign of Enlightened, though I'm pretty positive it meets the qualifications: there are no undeleted answers with an earlier timestamp (deleted answers [if there were any] don't count anyway) and the checkmark is hard to miss. Something wrong with the scripts?

I also notice that meta rep is similarly more than two hours behind, not that that really matters, but it's supposed to update every hour.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60323/276044

Comment: @Miniman: The inconsistency is annoying, but whatever; normally the badges come within seconds of each other. Hours is ... bizarre.

Comment: Elapsed time: 4h40m38s between badges.

Answer (score 8):

*Badges come as do

    Enlightenment and patience:

          On the wings of time*

Comment: This is why I don't play Monk. (just kidding)

Comment: Badges are delivered by the *Epoch*?

Comment: @Miniman But of course. What else did people think I meant?

Comment: This just makes SE even more awesome...

Comment: @Miniman TuggyNE's second badge obviously wasn't in the first shipment, so it came in on the next delivery.